# flutter moved all dependencies of pubspec.lock to pubspec.yaml to report an error

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

In order to control the version of all indirect dependencies, I moved all dependencies of `pubspec.lock` to `pubspec.yaml`. I compared the differences between `pubspec.yaml` and `pubspec.lock`, and finally `pubspec.yaml` looks like this:

```yaml
name: xxxx
description: A new flutter plugin project.
version: 0.0.1
homepage:

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.12.0 <3.0.0"
  flutter: ">=1.20.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  # flutter packages=========
  async: 2.6.1
  boolean_selector: 2.1.0
  characters: 1.1.0
  charcode: 1.2.0
  clock: 1.1.0
  collection: 1.15.0
  fake_async: 1.2.0
  ffi: 1.1.2
  matcher: 0.12.10
  meta: 1.3.0
  path: 1.8.0
  sky_engine: 0.0.99
  source_span: 1.8.1
  stack_trace: 1.10.0
  stream_channel: 2.1.0
  string_scanner: 1.1.0
  term_glyph: 1.2.0
  test_api: 0.3.0
  typed_data: 1.3.0
  vector_math: 2.1.0

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
```

Then I get an error：

> **pub get failed (1; Because xxx depends on sky_engine >=0.0.2 which
> requires SDK version <2.0.0, version solving failed.)**

The error is obvious, `sky_engine` requires SDK version `<2.0.0`. But sky_engine is a dependency of flutter sdk, everything worked before I moved to `pubspec.yaml`.

My questions:

1. Why does `sky_engine` work in `pubspec.lock` without version problems? If I don't lower the flutter sdk version, how can I solve the current problem?
2. If I want to control all indirect dependent versions, is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why does sky_engine work in pubspec.lock without version problems?

I'm not certain, but my guess is that the reference in Flutter is pulled from the Flutter SDK, but the way you've added it to your pubspec is trying to pull [this very old package](https://pub.dev/packages/sky_engine) from pub.

> If I don't lower the flutter sdk version, how can I solve the current problem?

You could just remove `sky_engine` from the list. It will be implicity versioned through your Flutter SDK. However:

> If I want to control all indirect dependent versions, is there a better way?

Yes, you would be better committing your `pubspec.lock` file (and only listing your specific dependencies in `pubspec.yaml`). This is suggested practice for your applications:

https://dart.dev/guides/libraries/private-files#pubspeclock

> **For application packages**, we recommend that you **commit** the `pubspec.lock` file. Saving `pubspec.lock` ensures that everyone working on the app uses the exact same versions.

However, if you're creating a package/reusable library, doing this may create unnecesary version constraints for projects using the package and therefore this might not be a good idea. You don't say *why* you're trying to do this though.

Comment: Yes, you are correct, `sky_engine` does depend on flutter sdk. thanks for your reminder.

Answer (score 0):

I re-checked the `pubspec.lock` file, and I found that the SDK depends on the way, and I wrote it wrong.
This is `pubspec.lock`:

```yaml
# Generated by pub
# See https://dart.dev/tools/pub/glossary#lockfile
packages:
  async:
    dependency: "direct main"
    description:
      name: async
      url: "https://pub.flutter-io.cn"
    source: hosted
    version: "2.6.1"
  boolean_selector:
    dependency: "direct main"
    description:
      name: boolean_selector
      url: "https://pub.flutter-io.cn"
    source: hosted
    version: "2.1.0"
  characters:
    dependency: "direct main"
    description:
      name: characters
      url: "https://pub.flutter-io.cn"
    source: hosted
    version: "1.1.0"
  charcode:
    dependency: "direct main"
    description:
      name: charcode
      url: "https://pub.flutter-io.cn"
    source: hosted
    version: "1.2.0"
  clock:
    dependency: "direct main"
    description:
      name: clock
      url: "https://pub.flutter-io.cn"
    source: hosted
    version: "1.1.0"
  collection:
    dependency: "direct main"
    description:
      name: collection
      url: "https://pub.flutter-io.cn"
    source: hosted
    version: "1.15.0"
  fake_async:
    dependency: "direct main"
    description:
      name: fake_async
      url: "https://pub.flutter-io.cn"
    source: hosted
    version: "1.2.0"
  ffi:
    dependency: "direct main"
    description:
      name: ffi
      url: "https://pub.flutter-io.cn"
    source: hosted
    version: "1.1.2"
  flutter:
    dependency: "direct main"
    description: flutter
    source: sdk
    version: "0.0.0"
  flutter_test:
    dependency: "direct dev"
    description: flutter
    source: sdk
    version: "0.0.0"
  matcher:
    dependency: "direct main"
    description:
      name: matcher
      url: "https://pub.flutter-io.cn"
    source: hosted
    version: "0.12.10"
  meta:
    dependency: "direct main"
    description:
      name: meta
      url: "https://pub.flutter-io.cn"
    source: hosted
    version: "1.3.0"
  path:
    dependency: "direct main"
    description:
      name: path
      url: "https://pub.flutter-io.cn"
    source: hosted
    version: "1.8.0"
  sky_engine:
    dependency: "direct main"
    description: flutter
    source: sdk
    version: "0.0.99"
  source_span:
    dependency: "direct main"
    description:
      name: source_span
      url: "https://pub.flutter-io.cn"
    source: hosted
    version: "1.8.1"
  stack_trace:
    dependency: "direct main"
    description:
      name: stack_trace
      url: "https://pub.flutter-io.cn"
    source: hosted
    version: "1.10.0"
  stream_channel:
    dependency: "direct main"
    description:
      name: stream_channel
      url: "https://pub.flutter-io.cn"
    source: hosted
    version: "2.1.0"
  string_scanner:
    dependency: "direct main"
    description:
      name: string_scanner
      url: "https://pub.flutter-io.cn"
    source: hosted
    version: "1.1.0"
  term_glyph:
    dependency: "direct main"
    description:
      name: term_glyph
      url: "https://pub.flutter-io.cn"
    source: hosted
    version: "1.2.0"
  test_api:
    dependency: "direct main"
    description:
      name: test_api
      url: "https://pub.flutter-io.cn"
    source: hosted
    version: "0.3.0"
  typed_data:
    dependency: "direct main"
    description:
      name: typed_data
      url: "https://pub.flutter-io.cn"
    source: hosted
    version: "1.3.0"
  vector_math:
    dependency: "direct main"
    description:
      name: vector_math
      url: "https://pub.flutter-io.cn"
    source: hosted
    version: "2.1.0"
sdks:
  dart: ">=2.12.0 <3.0.0"
  flutter: ">=1.20.0"
```

I found that the `sources` of `sky_engine`, `flutter`, and `flutter_test` are all `sdk`, and then I referred to the use of flutter and `flutter_test` in `pubspec.yaml`, so I got the following writing, it works.

```yaml
sky_engine:
    sdk: flutter
```

Coupled with @`Danny Tuppeny`'s suggestion, I now have two ways to control indirect dependencies:

1. Add all indirect dependencies to `pubspec.yaml`
2. The application of `pubspec.lock` commit to a remote repository